# How to send a startup message when my bot gets online in all servers it is in discord. Js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm basically trying to send my bot update log of commands I have removed and added along with its new version info and data as soon as I start it in my terminal or gets online in all server it's available in currently I'm trying this code :-

```js
Client.on{message.channel.send('Bot Name:- My bot \n Bot Verison :- 1.0.0 \n Owner :- Rega!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener from the [client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) to the [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event. Here's your code, corrected and reformated.

```js
// The callback gets called when the bot is ready
client.on('ready', () => {
  // Get the channel from its ID
  const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get('channel-id')
  // Send the message
  logChannel.send('The bot is up!')
})
```

You naturally need to replace `channel-id` with the ID of your channel. You can find more about it in this [Discord Support article](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-).